# $|S| < |T|$ implies $\dim(R⟨T⟩)>\dim(R⟨S⟩)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S, T$ be sets. Suppose $S$ is finite and $|S| < |T|$ ($T$ can be infinite). Let $f : R⟨T⟩ → R⟨S⟩$ be a linear application. Show that $\ker(f)≠\{0\}$.

I thought about solving it by the dimension theorem, but it is not clear to me if it can be done if T can be infinite. Furthermore, I’m not sure if $|S| < |T|$, implies $\dim(R⟨T⟩)>\dim(R⟨S⟩)$.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "$R\langle T\rangle $".

Comment: Even if you don't have the dimension theorem (which you can recover if you want), you still should have the isomorphism theorems; in particular, the "first isomorphism theorem".

Comment: If $R(S)$ denotes the linear span of $S,$ the conclusion holds if $R(S)\subsetneq R(T).$ The latter holds if $T$ is linearly independent.